# UITapGestureRecognizer in uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have one question about `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `UIPageViewController`

I have a `UILabel` labe1 in uiviewcontroller vc1 ,and vc1 is embedded in `UIPageViewController`.

Now I wanna to get the single tap event of label, but when in add the follow code in vc1 `viewDidLoad` function it doesn't work.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLabel1Tap)];
[_label addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

But if change the touch focus to self.view, it works well.

Anyone could give me some suggestion, It will be very appreciated.

Comment: Is `_label` instantiated i.e., connected via IBOutlet or instantiated with a frame ? and resides inside the bounds of self.view, i.e., did you set the correct constraints ?

Comment: Yes, for UI , everything is correct. the only issue is about uitapgesturerecognizer event detection.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the userinteraction property is not enabled, try this:

```
 [_label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Or change the color of the `_label` and parent view to make sure that the `_label` resides inside the parent view to successfully receive and handle touch events.